# Unixware: how to enable auditing for specific user?

Tags: audit, unixware

On Unixware I have enable auditing

```
auditon
```

create the map

```
auditmap
```

The log report is working

```
auditrpt -b
```

But only for root!

```
auditrpt -u root|wc -l
647
```

I try to set a mask for auditing for another user..

```
auditset -u myuser -e file_make 
UX:auditset: ERROR: auditevt() failed AGETUSR, errno = 3
```

How to enable auditing for user? Thanks